# Binding to Collection in DataGridRowHeader not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

My `DataGrid` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Entry>`.

```
public class Entry
{
     public List<string> Types {get; set;} = new List<string>() {"Type1", "Type2"};
}
```

Since `DataGrid.ItemsSource` is an Collection of `Entry` I expect the `DataContext` of a single `DataGridRow` to be typeof(`Entry`).

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Border Width="100">
              <StackPanel>                                
                  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Entries[0].Types, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
                  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" />
              </StackPanel>
          </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

The first `Binding` is working - the second is not.

Still I get no `BindingError`in the `Output`-Window of Visual Studio.

I need to show the `Types` for each `Entry` so access via index is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Types, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRowHeader}}" />
```

Comment: It is working ! Thanks alot ! Does that mean the binding is not recognized to come from a `DataGridRowHeader` ?

Comment: Yes, the DataTemplate doesn't inherit the DataContext from the DataGridRowHeader.